# For each Checkbox in Array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to hide a bunch of checkboxes based on an option button, but I keep getting "error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error":

```
Sub FU_EAL_PA_Toggle()
Dim cb As CheckBox
Dim MyCheckboxes As Variant
MyCheckboxes = Array( _
    "FU_EAL_PA1", _
    "FU_EAL_PA2", _
    "FU_EAL_PA3", _
    "FU_EAL_PA4", _
    "FU_EAL_PA5", _
    "FU_EAL_PA6", _
    "FU_EAL_PA7", _
    "FU_EAL_PA8", _
    "FU_EAL_PA8", _
    "FU_EAL_PA9", _
    "FU_EAL_PA10")

If ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("FU_PA_NotAttendingEAL").Value = 1 Then
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(MyCheckboxes)
        With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(MyCheckboxes)
            .Enabled = True
            .Visible = True
        End With
    Next cb
Else
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(MyCheckboxes)
        With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(MyCheckboxes)
            .Enabled = False
            .Visible = False
        End With
    Next cb
End If

End Sub
```

1. Is there a better way of doing this? (Note that I will be repeating this code for another subset of buttons, so I can't just cycle through all the controls on the sheet).
2. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you can Group the controls http://www.excelforcommerce.com/grouping-checkboxes-in-excel/ (or put them in a Group Box control) and then something like `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 1").Visible = (ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("FU_PA_NotAttendingEAL").Value = 1)`

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: updated to reflect your changes

```
Sub FU_EAL_PA_Toggle()

    Dim cb As CheckBox
    Dim bOK as Boolean
    Dim MyCheckboxes As Variant
    MyCheckboxes = Array( _
        "FU_EAL_PA1", _
        "FU_EAL_PA2", _
        "FU_EAL_PA3", _
        "FU_EAL_PA4", _
        "FU_EAL_PA5", _
        "FU_EAL_PA6", _
        "FU_EAL_PA7", _
        "FU_EAL_PA8", _
        "FU_EAL_PA8", _
        "FU_EAL_PA9", _
        "FU_EAL_PA10")

    bOK = (ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("FU_PA_NotAttendingEAL").Value = 1)

    For Each cb In MyCheckboxes
        With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(cb)
                .Enabled = bOK
                .Visible = bOK
        End With
    Next cb

    'or without the array...
    For x = 1 To 10
        With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("FU_EAL_PA" & x)
                .Enabled = bOK
                .Visible = bOK
        End With
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: You're right, I meant for the second half of the IF statement to toggle the checkboxes to False. edited the original.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround (BUT: Read to the bottom, because there's an easier way):

Rather than build an array to manage my grouping, I realized my naming convention was sufficient to allow for grouping:

```
Public Sub FU_EAL_PA_ToggleNew()

Dim cb As CheckBox

If ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("FU_PA_NotAttendingEAL").Value = 1 Then
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If Left(cb.Name, 9) = "FU_EAL_PA" Then
            cb.Visible = True
            cb.Enabled = True
        End If
    Next cb
Else
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If Left(cb.Name, 9) = "FU_EAL_PA" Then
            cb.Visible = False
            cb.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next cb
End If

End Sub
```

BUT, Slai's response above was WAY simpler:

> you can Group the controls [excelforcommerce.com/grouping-checkboxes-in-excel][1] (or put them in a Group Box control) and then something like:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("FU_EAL_PA").Visible = _
(ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("FU_PA_NotAttendingEAL").Value = 1)
```

Which I did, and it worked exactly as intended.

Thank you!